SSIS OnError Propagete set to False - still propagating to parent containers
I have an SSIS package with a Data Flow Task (Word to DB Data Flow Task) that is inside a sequence container that is inside of several loops. "Word to DB Data Flow Task" can sometimes fail and I want to capture that failure and continue through the parent Container and Loops.  I have created an OnError event handler for "Word to DB Data Flow Task" and set it's  Propagation to False.
The parent container still receives the Error which propagates all the way up and fails the package.

This is the OnError event that I set:

I have been using this article as a guide:
https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/08/05/continue-package-execution-after-error-in-ssis/
I don't want to mess around with the MaximumErrorCount on the parent loops because I want the package to be able to fail from other components.
I don't see why it still "bubbles up" the chain
